# Why does SSRS Independent parameter is cascading by default

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, reporting, bids

I have a report which currently has four parameters

```
1) BatchID
2) ProductName  (dropdown parameter populated based on the batch ID)
3) StartDateTime (Date/time parameter with default value set to =Now)
4) EndDateTime (Date/time parameter with default value set to =Now)
```

When I run the report the StartDateTime and EndDateTime are greyed out why? As they are independent parameters I would have thought it will be enabled by default.

The next question I have is the delay, after entering the first parameter the second parameter is populated as expected. However after selecting the second parameter from the dropdown. There is a delay of over 30 seconds to populate the StartDateTime and EndDateTime parameter(s) with the current datetime.

I don't know if I did a good job in explaining my question. Any help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the problem of having a disabled date type of parameter for SSRS only occurs when the date/time parameter’s default value is an expression like `=Now`. If the default value is not set or is set to a literal value like `1/1/2018`, the control functions as expected — it is enabled.

"Parameter order is important when you want to show users the default value for one parameter before they choose values for other parameters"

Ref:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281392.aspx

The controls after non-default parameters are disabled the user picks something, so order is important. The date/time control won’t be enabled until it evaluates its default value expression. It is stated that the delay you mentioned here is intended to allow this parameter’s expression to use the proceeding parameter’s value in its computation.

Ref2: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2011/03/02/595/ssrs-datetime-parameter-disabled-when-default-value-expression-is-used